# Tkinker How to loop through images?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a lot og base64 images stored in a pandas dataframe `df_time_text_frames`. Now, I would like to make a simple program, that shows me the images and has a button NEXT, or PREVIOUS, to navigate through the images.

I tried:

I define a function `load_next_img` which is triggered when I press the `tk.Button` called `next` and which should then display the frame given by a global `counter` which increments every time I press this buttom.

Not yet implemented:

I would have a similar function for the buttom `previous` which would subtract 1 from the global variable `counter`

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image


global counter
counter = 0
def load_next_img(counter):
    global tk_image
    image_data_base64_encoded_string = df_time_text_frames["Frame_(base_64)"][counter]
    image = tk.PhotoImage(image_data_base64_encoded_string)
    tk.Label(root, image=im).pack()
    counter += 1

root =  tk.Tk() 

nextbutton = tk.Button(text="next", command=load_next_img(counter))
nextbutton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

First of all, it does not work. I get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TclError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-bc9ac8d3c57e> in <module>()
     14 root =  tk.Tk()
     15 root = tk.Toplevel()
---> 16 nextbutton = tk.Button(text="next", command=load_next_img(counter))
     17 nextbutton.pack()
     18 

<ipython-input-24-bc9ac8d3c57e> in load_next_img(counter)
      9     image_data_base64_encoded_string = df_time_text_frames["Frame_(base_64)"][counter]
     10     image = tk.PhotoImage(image_data_base64_encoded_string)
---> 11     tk.Label(root, image=im).pack()
     12     counter += 1
     13 

~\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py in __init__(self, master, cnf, **kw)
   2761 
   2762         """
-> 2763         Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)
   2764 
   2765 class Listbox(Widget, XView, YView):

~\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py in __init__(self, master, widgetName, cnf, kw, extra)
   2294             del cnf[k]
   2295         self.tk.call(
-> 2296             (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
   2297         for k, v in classes:
   2298             k.configure(self, v)

TclError: image "pyimage8" doesn't exist
```

...and I am wondering, if there is a much easier/better way to do it ?

**EDIT 1:** 
I tried the following:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image


global counter
counter = 0


def load_next_img(counter):
    #global counter
    # rest of your code
    counter += 1
    global tk_image
    image_data_base64_encoded_string = df_time_text_frames["Frame_(base_64)"][counter]
    image = tk.PhotoImage(image_data_base64_encoded_string)
    tk.Label(root, image=im).pack()
    counter += 1

root =  tk.Tk() 

nextbutton = tk.Button(text="next", 
                        command=lambda counter: load_next_image(counter))
nextbutton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I get no error, but the image does not display.

Answer (score 2):

I see a few issues with this that may or may not be the cause of the problem.

1. There is no need to have counter as an argument to load_next_image since you have already declared it globally. Remove counter as an argument and include counter in the functions namespace like this:

```py
global counter
counter = 0
def load_next_image():
    global counter
    # rest of your code
    counter += 1
```

2. Writing `command=load_next_image(counter)` isn't doing what you think it's doing. Command accepts either 'None' or a callable object like a function. What you are doing is setting command equal to the output of `load_next_image(counter)` when the button is created which is None since `load_next_image` doesn't return anything.

   If you don't need to pass any parameters to the function, the correct way is `command=load_next_image` which sets command equal to the actual function handle. When the button is clicked, your function will execute.

   If you do need to pass an argument to the function (sometimes necessary), you should use a `lambda` statement (see [this](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda)).

```py
 nextbutton = tk.Button(text="next", 
                        command=lambda counter: load_next_image(counter))
```

Again, this works because lambda returns a handle to an anonymous function and not the result of the function itself. However in your case, you don't need to worry about this if you implement counter as a global variable like I mentioned in (1) (since you don't need to pass an argument).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please have a look at my updated question. Maybe you can spot my mistake ? Thanks !

Comment: I'm not sure what `im` is when you do `tk.Label(root, image=im).pack()`. As Rohan suggested in his answer you should probably change that to `tk.Label(root, image=image).pack()`.